# tableView dataSource not available at compile time but at run time

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Using UITableView with one Prototype cell inside a ContainerView. The table will need to provide cells so that at run time, the code will add different views in different cells for user information and interaction.
The connection is made between the tableView and the containerView.swift to be its dataSource and delegate.

In the containerView.swift, the UIViewController has been extended.

`extension myContainerView: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {...}`

And in that block of code, there are required func which return **numberOfRowsInSection** and **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

But these infos are available at run time and thus my code is not complying now, I get this following error when `return parent.mainTbRowCount()` is reached, and if I return just a dummy int for now, I get the same error when  `let view = parent.cellsViewsDesider.views![indexPath.row]` is reached.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
extension myContainer: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return parent.mainTbRowCount() // <------ fatal error
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("topCellId", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let view = parent.cellsViewsDesider.views![indexPath.row]  // <---- fatal error 
    cell.contentView.addSubview(view!)
    return cell
}
```

If I delete the connection which I made between the tableView and the containerView.swift to be its dataSource and delegate, the code compiles but the functions for  **numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath** never get called.

What needs to be done in this case?

Thank you

Comment: Not compiling? What's the error? Where? Also, you'll need to provide the relevant parts of your code. Also not sure why you would need a container view...

Comment: Please notice, I have updated the question, Container is needed because parts of the screen is used by another container  thx

Comment: Right click on the tableView inside the Document Outline area and deleted the dataSource and delegate Outlets fixed the problem, but Is not that needed to populate the table? How can that table show the newly populated cells in run time?

Comment: By default, an `UITableViewController` sets itself as data source and delegate of the tableview it creates.  But what is `parent`? Still don't know why you would need the whole container stuff. Just add a tableview to your view controller's view and assign its data source and delegate to the view controller (i.e., no `UITableViewController`)

Comment: Please note, I updated the question, UITableViewController is not used here, just the tableView inside the container. The container is needed because the main storyBoard contains other containers for other reasons plus the storyBoard has another tableView for other purposes. Now the app runs but the tableView in question is empty where I expected to see some views according to cellForRowAtIndexPath. ;) thx –